# What are the different sleep modes on Mavericks MacBook Pros?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-management, power-nap, app-nap

I'm confused about the different sleep modes on Mavericks MacBook Pros: PowerNap, App Nap, DarkWake, sleep, system sleep, display sleep, standby, hibernation, etc.?

What do these terms mean and how do they differ. In particular

1. what triggers each (e.g., closing the lid, period of inactivity, etc.)
2. what things are on and off (e.g., network connections, drives, etc.)
3. what applications and code still runs, and
4. what can "wake" (or otherwise change the state of) the system in each mode (e.g., network activity, which kinds of scheduled tasks, etc.)?

---

FWIW, on my machine, `pmset -g` reports (what I believe are the defaults):

```
System-wide power settings:
 DestroyFVKeyOnStandby      0
Active Profiles:
Battery Power         1
AC Power             -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                1
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: There's a detailed discussion here of the various hibernate modes: http://etherealmind.com/osx-hibernate-mode/

Comment: @bills: Is that current as of Mavericks?

Comment: You certainly have the `pmset` command and the same three modes, but it is an older post, so I'm not 100% sure about everything else...